# File Upload issue in JMeter, Content-Transfer Encoding appended to header request

Tags: jmeter, content-type

I am facing a problem with JMeter while uploading files. Server is Apache Tomcat
On comparing the POST data between the browser and JMeter, I found that 
this line is coming extra in JMeter request 
**Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary** and it is not there in the browser request captured through Fiddler.

I even recorded and exported the script to JMeter from Badboy, even then, I am not able to find a solution.

Is there any way to turn it off from the JMeter request. Or Is it due to an issue in Server side code.

Does anyone encountered this type of issue, please share your ideas on how to handle this?

Comment: Please post a screenshot of the sampler that sending the upload request.

Comment: I have the same problem as yours.  Have you resolved it?

Answer (score 0):

In Jmeter version 5.1.1, we won't see the "Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary" in the "View Results Tree" request header, if you have enabled "browser-compatible header" in HTTP Request-

[image: Example]